# Tetragrammaton in Public at? Allowed? Not Allowed?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

Found a photo of the [Great Synagogue of Tunis](http://www.dw.com/en/the-last-jews-in-tunisia/a-16536946) and emblazoned on the outside of the synagogue, is a very large tetragramaton that is visible for all to see from the street or courtyard. Is there any halakha forbidding this, or allowing it? It's not something one sees often so wondering what the story behind it is.

[image: photo of front of great synagogue of tunis]

Comment: Either way, they have some kerning issues.

Comment: @magicker72 What is kerning?

Comment: @Aaron http://xkcd.com/1015/

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/name.htm